# CSS Border Being Applied to Unwanted Element (Have tried everything to remove it)

Tags: css, html, border

I created a 200x200 square div and created a dashed border to define it.

The problem is that the div right above it, completely unrelated, is also getting a dashed border applied to it. If I add other divs, they do not experience the problem. Just my title text.

Here is an image!

[image: an image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qod6.png

And here is the HTML/CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<h1>Test Text</h1>  
</div>
<div id="dropbox">
    <p>Drag and drop your file here!</p>
    <img src="spinner.gif" />
</div>
</body>
</html>

html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", sans-serif;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 15%, from(#2B2B2B), to(#383838)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #2B2B2B, #383838);
margin: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#main h1{
border: none;
padding-top: 4em;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-size: 250%;
text-decoration: none;  
color: #ffffff;
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px white; 
text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #292929;
}
#dropbox {
border-style:dashed;
border-width:5px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
font-family: Georgia, "HelveticaNeue-Light", sans-serif;
font-color: #222;
font-size:105%;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #555;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: lol at your name. and do you mean the text has a border?

Comment: can't reproduce in IE. Are you using Chrome?

Comment: Yes this glitch occurs in Chrome. I plan no IE compatibility.
Ima Student - as in the picture, yes, the title text has a border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Chrome dev tools it appears your `-webkit-text-stroke` on the text is causing this error; probably due to a -webkit bug or something.  When i remove it it fixes the border issue and doesn't otherwise affect the text.

Comment: I love you! I wish I could vote up this answer, but stackoverflow won't let me.

I'm wondering how you got dev tools to tell you this. I'm looking around and getting nothing from my dev tools...

Comment: @DislikesBorders this screenshot shows what i did. Notice how i unchecked the checkbox on the -webkit-text-stroke: https://picasaweb.google.com/117621119706045694917/ChromeDev#5600476390507204514

Comment: Ahaa. Guess and check. Teaches me a good lesson on not to overlook the seemingly obvious solutions. Hat off to you sir! :)